# Items not getting added to cart

Tags: magento-1.9

I am trying to add a number of items in cart given an array of product Ids but it  is adding only the first product.

```
 $approverCart= Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
 foreach($itemIds as $itemId){     
 $item = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item')->load($itemId);

      $qty= $item->getQty();
      $productId= $item->getData('product_id');
      $pModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
      $approverCart->addProduct($pModel, array('product'=>$productId,'qty' => $qty));
      echo $productId." ".$qty."<br>";
      $approverCart->save();

      }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$products = explode(',', $this->getRequest()->getParam('products'));
        $cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart');
        $cart->init();
        /* @var $pModel Mage_Catalog_Model_Product */
        foreach ($products as $product_id) {
            if ($product_id == '') {
                continue;
            }
            $pModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
            if ($pModel->getTypeId() == Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_SIMPLE) {
                try {
                    $cart->addProduct($pModel, array('qty' => '1'));
                }
                catch (Exception $e) {
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
        $cart->save();
        if ($this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
            exit('1');
        }
        $this->_redirect('checkout/cart');
```

also visit

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16952580/add-multiple-products-to-cart-in-magento-1-7-0-2

**I hope this will help you.**

Answer (score 0):

please try this

```
 $cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart');
 foreach($itemIds as $itemId){   

      $item = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item')->load($itemId);    
      $qty= $item->getQty();
      $productId= $item->getData('product_id');
      $pModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);


      $cart->init();
      $cart->addProduct($pModel, array('qty' => $qty));
      $cart->save();
      Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true); 

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you have a bug in your code, the `$approverCart->save();` method should be called after all products are added to cart object with `addProduct()` method, means after the `foreach` loop is completed.

Try as below:

```
$approverCart= Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
foreach($itemIds as $itemId) {
    $item = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item')->load($itemId);
    $qty= $item->getQty();
    $productId= $item->getData('product_id');
    $pModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
    $approverCart->addProduct($pModel, array('product'=>$productId,'qty' => $qty));
    echo $productId." ".$qty."<br>";
}

$approverCart->save();
```

This will loop through all products already in quote object and add them to cart and then atlast it will save whole cart object.

> **Cart's `save()` method will execute only once and then it's properties/variables are reset.**

Not sure why that happens, but this will resolve your issue for sure.

Comment: @Krrish Raj If any of the answers posted here have solved your issue, then please mark it as accepted, so any other visitor who has encountered the same issue as yours can get help from here.